# replace \\ with \ using Replace()

Tags: c#

Check the code bellow. I am trying to find `\\` and replace with `\` single back slash but it seems `Replace()` method can't do that. I keep getting the same result on `test2` variable.

How can I fix this?

```
string test1 = "C:\\Users\\lik\\Desktop\\foo\\BacklogExcelGenerator\\bin\\Debug\\foo.xlsx";


string test2 = test1.Replace("\\", @"\");
```

Comment: In a C# string \\ is how you represent a single \ so what your attempting is probably not necessary. (If you looked at test1 in the debugger you would again see \\ but in reality - when you print or display the string elsewhere - there is only a single \ present)

Comment: but `"\\"` *is* a single slash...

Comment: Yes, `test1` *doesn't* contain any double backslashes. Be wary, the C# debugger likes to show you "What you would have to write in C# source code for a string literal" rather than "the exact current contents of the string". So if that's where you're looking and seeing a problem, it's not real.

Comment: Usually when expressing a path we would use the `@` symbol to indicate that the contained text is a string literal: `@"C:\Users\lik\Desktop\foo\BacklogExcelGenerator\bin\Debug\foo.xlsx"`

Comment: @John Doe , I ran the code that you wrote, please make sure again to verify that it is working, it is working for me perfectly. Here is the shot : https://ibb.co/XyLsh49

Comment: @affanBajwa I believe the issue is a gap in understanding escape characters and not the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\` is used as an escape character in strings. Escape characters are used to encode special "non printed" characters inside a string like `\n` is new line `\"` is a quote etc. Because `\` is the escape character, in order to write a `\` we have to escape it and write it as `\\` this shows up as a double slash in code and if you view the string in a debugger but both in memory and when it's printed to the screen it appears as 1.

For instance

```
string s = "The quick \"brown\" fox jumped\nOver the lazy dog. \\\\o_o//";
```

will print to the screen as

```
The quick "brown" fox jumped
Over the lazy dog.\\o_o//
```

Some light reading on [escape sequences](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/escape-sequences-c/) and you'll be good to go

Verbatim strings, made in C# by `@""` will treat everything as literal and don't have escape characters, if you want a newline you have to write the string over 2 lines. The only escape you can do in a verbatim string is `"` and that's done by `""`

```
string s = @"The quick ""brown"" fox jumped
Over the lazy dog. \\o_o/";
```

will have the same output as the escaped string above

```
The quick "brown" fox jumped
Over the lazy dog.\\o_o//
```

Answer (score 0):

`"\\"` and `@"\"` are equal strings that contain on character slash `'\'`. So, Your method replaces `'\'` with `'\'`.

`\` is a special character, that uses for declaring some others values like `\n` - new line, `\t` - tab and so on. And single slash is written as `\\`.

Read more in article [Escape Sequences](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/h21280bw(v=vs.140)).

Answer (score 0):

you are missing a @ in the `\\` to replace, remember that `\` is a escape character so you are only asking for one bar for the compiler
in the end you should have something like this to replace the double bar

```
string test2 = test1.Replace(@"\\", @"\");
```

In that way you will indicate that the `\\` is literal too

Comment: note, however, that in the context of the question as asked: there is no double-slash to replace in the first place

Comment: You're right. the string does not have any double slash to replace because is not literal either. Good catch

Comment: There is no point telling the OP how to 'improve' / change their second line. The problem isn't with the second line - the problem is that he/she doesn't **need** the second line, and doesn't understand that yet. _The OP's original second line does nothing, while your new code does a slightly different nothing (based on the OP's `test1` value)._